# Error using ember-rails gem: "Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars 1.0.beta.5 or greater"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm using Ember JS for the first time. It's for use in a Rails project and I'm using the ember-rails gem. I've followed the instructions on the ember-rails GitHub.

After `bundle install` I run `rails g ember:bootstrap` to kick things off. I then also add the following two lines to application.js:

```
//= require ember

App = Ember.Application.create();
```

The issue is that when I visit localhost:3000/, I get the following JavaScript errors logged to the console:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars 1.0.beta.5 or greater :3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:43
Uncaught ReferenceError: DS is not defined :3000/assets/store.js?body=1:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'template' of undefined :3000/assets/templates/application.js?body=1:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'template' of undefined :3000/assets/templates/application.js?body=1:1
Uncaught Error: <HotDoc.ApplicationView:ember138> - Unable to find template "application".
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.6.

Any ideas how I can resolve these issues? As far as I understand it, ember-rails includes the Handlebars code so I don't need to add any other gems.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ember 1.0.pre they've unbundled Handlebars. You need to provide it yourself. Looks like ember-rails assumes the same thing.

**Edit**

You need to add at the top of the file

```
//= require handlebars
```

Comment: I don't think so, take a look at this: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/blob/master/vendor/ember/development/handlebars.js Handlebars looks included

Comment: Looks like ember-rails is running `Version: v0.9.1-1490-g0dc82cc` for me. If I include the handlebars-rails gem I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @ChrisNolet, try //= require handlebars before //=require ember

Comment: It works! I didn't need handlebars-rails, just the `//= require handlebars` part. Thanks for the update ;) Much appreciated.